# Localhost sent an invalid response for my angular app

Tags: angular, apache, maven, ssl, localhost

I have a project in my local created with springBoot, java, jHipster, Angular, etc and I want to run it. Usually I have used mvnw to run the project. Now I changed computer so when running mvnw in cmd it says app running in https://localhost:8080 and when I go to this link I cannot have access to the app.

This is the message:

```html
This site can’t provide a secure connection
localhost sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Maybe I need to install apache so I can access to the projects in localhost? I do not remeember if I had apache installed in my old pc wheer I could access to teh app.

I did `netstat -ano | findstr 8080` in cmd and found in task manager that port 8080 is used by java.exe. Maybe it is a port issue?
Thanks!

Comment: on the angular.json file, go to architect -> serve -> builder -> configuration and after browserTarget, add the host option like this, "host": "127.0.0.1", and it should work like a charm

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You have to use the `HTTP` protocol instead, as you don't need to use a `SSL Certificate`.

Change it from:

```
https://localhost:8080
```

To:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Then you should not have the error again.

Comment: I do not see the reason of your answer but it was teh other way around.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! The reason why I had the problem was that I was using https instead of http that could be the right one. Sorry your answer seems to say the otherway around.

Comment: Again I want to accept your answer but for the other people it may be confusing. Just change the places of protocols. That's all. Just because you helped me it is not enough. The question gotta be helpful for others too.

Comment: Accepted! Hey people, http protocol helps in this case. So my bad to use https instead of http.

Comment: I have tried that, but it automatically changes to "https" when I enter

Comment: To assume that you don't need https is not a correct assumption. for example if you depend on external authentication that use OIDC and client_id.

Comment: What a difference a year makes, @ph33nyx... Chrome 68+ now forces https.  For Angular apps, you can add another line to your package.json "scripts" section. I use:
    "start": "ng serve --port 4200",
    "startSSL": "ng serve --ssl --port 4200",

Starting the site as startSSL will allow you to run SSL on localhost
(NOTE: might also require withCredentials: true to be added to your HttpInterceptor)

Comment: It works if you use the IP: 127.0.0.1:8080

Answer (score 58):

If changing to http does not work for you:
in your chromium based browser, go to url:

- for chrome: `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`
- for edge: `edge://net-internals/#hsts`
- for brave: `brave://net-internals/#hsts`

Under **Delete domain security policies** enter `localhost` or your problem domain and click the delete button on screen

Comment: Also works on edge `edge://net-internals/#hsts`

Comment: After deleting localhost with this approach, tried loading with `http://localhost` instead of `https://localhost` and it worked.

Comment: Why did this suddenly change though? I was messing around with Docker yesterday but I can't figure out what change I made that would cause this issue.

Comment: this worked for me after restarting the browser window

Answer (score 2):

I have a same problem with google chrome. After check offered solutions, it's not worked. (Even I used http instead of https, but chrome redirect itself to https).
So I used Mozilla Firefox and Microsoft Edge, it worked! I don't know how to resolve it in google chrome!
Have you any offer about this?

Comment: Correct working in mozilla firefox

Comment: In 2023, it doesn't work in Firefox either.

Comment: @CetinBasoz you got any solution for this?

Comment: @AmalPs, not directly. Instead, using LetsEncrypt I created https for localhost. Or as a second solution use ngrok tunneling which always have https.

Comment: @CetinBasoz okay that's cool lemme try something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior because you don't use the https protocol.

Answer (score 1):

if you are opening in 'localhost' , then you have to provide http, because the local computer cannot provide a secure connection(https).
so, try this....

Answer (score 0):

I know this has a solution, but in case you are still endountering the issue after changing `https` to `http` in the URL, then your chorme browser might always redirect the `localhost` to `https`. This guide should help in that case: https://howchoo.com/chrome/stop-chrome-from-automatically-redirecting-https

Answer (score 0):

It also happens when we accidentally use wrong environment key. After checking all chrome related solutions, I found that the env key was invalid. Putting the correct one solves this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `Powershell`
2. `cd` to your app folder
3. Run `ng serve --ssl --port 4200` and `Enter`
4. Go to `Chrome` and enter `https://localhost:4200/`
5. You will get the warning: `Your connection isn't private`
6. Click `Advanced` and click on `Continue to localhost (unsafe)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was very simple to solve.

The correct way to open localhost is: http://... but the browser is saving https://... in cache, just clear the browser's cache and it will work.

Comment: This behavior is going to vary by browser (and possibly version), so please add more specific info to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having an issue in Chrome, try this:

chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

[Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate/31900210#31900210)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here as I did, I had to use the IPv6 notation in the Chrome address bar for the "generic" Angular app after ng serve had finished:

http://[::1]:4200/

[::1] is the IPv6 address for localhost. On my system a "ping localhost" resulted in this IPv6 address being pinged, not the IPv4 address 127.0.0.1.